# compilation issues - cheese webcam on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to compile cheese from source code (I need to add a new functionality to the source code) and I am getting some errors that I am not finding solutions for online.

1. I cloned using:  git clone git://git.gnome.org/cheese (and even tried 'sudo git clone...' at some point)
2. cd cheese (the new directory that was created by git clone)
3. sudo autoconf (./configre won't run yet but I have a configure.ac)

now - I am getting the below errors:

```
configure.ac:14: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
configure.ac:15: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_MAINTAINER_MODE
configure.ac:16: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_SILENT_RULES
configure.ac:20: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_PROG_CC_C_O
configure.ac:22: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_PROG_VALAC
configure.ac:80: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_MSG_RESULT
configure.ac:88: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_DEFINE
configure.ac:89: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_MSG_ERROR
configure.ac:97: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_CONDITIONAL
configure.ac:117: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_MSG_WARN
```

a thread with a similar issue suggested to run autoreconf --install, I did, resulting in:

```
configure.ac:210: error: macro APPSTREAM_XML is not defined; is a m4 
file missing?
m4/ax_require_defined.m4:35: AX_REQUIRE_DEFINED is expanded from...
configure.ac:210: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: error: echo failed with exit status: 1
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
```

I looked that up but didn't manage to sense of what I was reading.

I would very much appreciate some general explanation for what is wrong here and specifically how to solve this and compile.

Answer (score 1):

To compile Gnome Cheese Webcam software:

Under new distributions (e.g. Debian testing, Ubuntu, etc.)

```
apt-get install git
git clone https://git.gnome.org/browse/cheese
cd cheese

apt-get install autoconf gtk-doc-tools yelp-tools appstream-util libx11-dev libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev libgnome-desktop-3-dev libclutter-gtk-1.0-dev libclutter-gst-3.0-dev libcanberra-gtk3-dev valac

./autogen.sh
./configure
make -j4
```

Under older distributions (e.g. Debian Jessie), checkout an older tag (e.g. 3.14.1) first:

```
apt-get install git
git clone https://git.gnome.org/browse/cheese
cd cheese
git tag                  ## view  tags
git checkout 3.14.1      ## older tag

apt-get install autoconf gtk-doc-tools yelp-tools appstream-util libglib2.0-dev libx11-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev libgnome-desktop-3-dev libclutter-gtk-1.0-dev libclutter-gst-2.0-dev libcanberra-gtk3-dev libgudev-1.0-dev valac

./autogen.sh
./configure
make -j4
```

Answer (score 0):

When I tried building the latest version of cheese (git commit 0a6032b9a41116f4ee2b59cd56c0049aa35ded4f) on Debian Sid/Buster, a build dependency was missing from the list in the accepted answer (gnome-common). I've updated the list of commands to include this dependency:

```
apt-get install git
git clone https://git.gnome.org/browse/cheese
cd cheese

apt-get install autoconf gtk-doc-tools yelp-tools appstream-util libx11-dev libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev libgnome-desktop-3-dev libclutter-gtk-1.0-dev libclutter-gst-3.0-dev libcanberra-gtk3-dev valac gnome-common

./autogen.sh
./configure
make -j4
```